# Stacking Regression Plots from two separate locations in one study on R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, regression

I am trying to stack to regression plots on top of each other. I've used the facet_wrap function to stack histograms but not sure how to apply it to this function. Essentially I am wanting to stack regression plots for two separate locations in my study. for each location this is my code for the individual regression lines:

```
ggplot(oceanregression, aes(x=log_phosphorus, y=chl.a_mg.m3))+
  geom_point(col="black", size=2.5)+
  xlab("log phosphorus nmol/L")+
  ylab("Concentration of Chl in mg/m3")+
  theme_classic()+
  geom_smooth(method=lm, formula=y~x)
```

Comment: Hi @orangepeelsoup, could you please share your data using `dput(df)`? So we can help you better.

Comment: Any issue with faceting your plot by location? As long as your dataset contains data for both locations you could do e.g.`+ facet_wrap(~location)`.

Answer (score 0):

For separate regression lines on the same plot/facet you can do this:

```
ggplot(oceanregression, aes(x=log_phosphorus, y=chl.a_mg.m3, color=location))+
  geom_point(col="black", size=2.5)+
  xlab("log phosphorus nmol/L")+
  ylab("Concentration of Chl in mg/m3")+
  theme_classic()+
  geom_smooth(method=lm, formula=y~x)
```

[image: stackocean]

If you want to have split into facets, you can do this:

```
ggplot(oceanregression, aes(x=log_phosphorus, y=chl.a_mg.m3, color=location))+
  geom_point(col="black", size=2.5)+
  xlab("log phosphorus nmol/L")+
  ylab("Concentration of Chl in mg/m3")+
  theme_classic()+
  facet_wrap(~location)+
  geom_smooth(method=lm, formula=y~x)
```

[image: facet_ocean]

Input Data:

```
set.seed(123)
oceanregression = data.table(
  location=c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 10)),
  log_phosphorus = rep(1:10,2),
  chl.a_mg.m3 = rnorm(20)
)
```